# Error: Only variables should be passed by reference error?

Tags: php

This is the relevant code. Others have faced similar issues on stack overflow but tried a couple of those solutions and didn't seem to work in this case. It seems part of the code needs to be stored in a variable and then that variable stored in $path.

```
$path = ltrim( end( @explode( get_template(), str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ), '/' );
```

This is occurring on the latest version on Ubuntu.

Comment: What PHP version are you using and what is the output of get_template?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer depends of version of PHP you are using, but candidate is END function.

Anyway, this code will work always:

```
$templatePath = str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
$templatePathArray = @explode( get_template(), $templatePath );
$lastDir = end($templatePathArray);
$path = ltrim( $lastDir, '/' );
```

PS. Are you sure you are using right separator in explode?

Comment: Thanks for getting back, PHP 7.0.8. I'll try the above!

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!